# Providing no-js fallbacks for clientside MV* frameworks

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js, client-side, fallback

I just recently got introduced to MV* frameworks and have taken a chance to try out [Ember.js](http://emberjs.com/) with the [TodoMVC](http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/planning-the-application/) app tutorial they have on their site.

I was considering using Ember for one of my upcoming projects (a [Ruby on Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/) CRUD app, similar to Twitter in some of the functionality), but I'm still a bit confused and before I take a final decision I would love it if somebody could clear the following concerns:

1. Is it a good idea to use such an advanced framework as Ember for a medium-sized multi-page CRUD app? Will it improve development time and maintenance compared to an interactivity layer built with jQuery's DOM manipulation and AJAX capabilities? Or is using Ember (and the like) only good when developing complex single-page apps (e.g.: [Grooveshark](http://grooveshark.com/))?
2. Considering the app will be developed using Rails, and assuming Ember will be used, is it going to be possible to offer a fallback with basic functionality for browsers with JavaScript disabled and/or for search engine crawlers? Will it require code duplication or other dirty tricks? Do you know of any technique that can be used to achieve it?
3. Will it be possible to adapt the website for mobile browsing (using only CSS) with valid results, or will the overhead imposed by running Ember on the phone make it hard for the device to render the website in a way that keeps it responsive?

Answer (score 3):

We're in the middle of a pretty big Ember project right now, so here are my thoughts on your questions.

1. We've found Ember to be really productive for creating rich UIs for our single page app, but I don't know that it's going to be that much more helpful if you're creating an app designed for traditional multi-page (viewing pages, submitting forms, etc) layout.
2. I think this is the clincher - Ember is completely JS-based, so if you need to support browsers without JS, you'd basically have to write a parallel application. If this is a hard requirement for your app, I think Ember (or any MV* JS framework) would be out of the question
3. We've had very few performance issues on mobile - our site is fully responsive and renders on everything from Blackberries to the latest Chrome on desktop with good performance.

Comment: For the second point, you could have a look at http://www.appscharts.me. This site uses Backbone, and provide graceful degradation for disabled js browsers and search engines.

Answer (score 0):

@Scott Rankin, has addressed most of the concerns with going with the Pure Ember approach. I'll add one quick way to make this decision.

Go with Ember/MVVM if the application is behind a login. Then you don't have to consider search engines, as the content is generally private and not supposed to be indexed.

For SEO you have to build atleast part of your content such that it is indexable. A good example of this is the [Discourse](http://www.discourse.org) application. They use Ember but also send down some generated html along with the app html slugs, so that search engines can index them. You can read about their approach [here](http://eviltrout.com/2013/06/19/adding-support-for-search-engines-to-your-javascript-applications.html).

Answer (score 0):

We have a different approach which can be seen as a fall back: We pre-render a static version of each page in the application (daily scheduled task). This static version is stored on the server as HTML file. Whenever we sniff as spider/ robot user agent, we deliver that version.